# $ X $ a Markov chain has value in $\{1,2,3\}$ with transiton matrix $P$

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

$ X $ a Markov chain has value in $\{1,2,3\}$ with transiton matrix $P$ the transition matrix and $u = (u_1, u_2, u_3)$ the law of $X_0$. What is $P (X_0 = 1, X_1 = 1, X_2 = 3, X_3 = 2)$ as a function of $P$ and $u$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $P_{ij}$ denotes the probability of transitioning from state $i$ to state $j$. Then
\begin{align}
 P(X_{0}=1, X_{1}=1, X_{2}=3, X_{3}=2) &= P(X_{3}=2|X_{2}=3)\cdot P(X_{2}=3|X_{1}=1)\cdots \\
&\cdot P(X_{1}=1|X_{0}=1)\cdot P(X_{0}=1)\\
&=P_{32}P_{13}P_{11}u_{1}
\end{align}